Недавно, перешёл на препроцессор sass(scss) и не понимаю в чём проблема
Я работаю при помощи саблайма, через prepros, но есть проблема. У меня, в файле style.scss не работают ни плагины, которые ускоряют работу написания кода, ни цвет темы(color scheme). В css всё это есть.
